# Tratamento da exceção ArithmeticException

Tags: java

Olá, tem alguma forma de usar a Exceção "ArithmeticException" na divisão por zero no mesmo try/catch e o programa ainda mostrar os resultados? Quando informo o segundo valor como "0" ele informa só a exceção e não mostra o resultado das outras "operações"!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a,b,soma,resto,sub,div,mult;
    String entrada;

    try{
    entrada =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe um número inteiro");
    a = Integer.parseInt(entrada);

    entrada =JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe outro número inteiro");
    b = Integer.parseInt(entrada);

    soma  = a + b;
    sub   = a - b;
    mult  = a * b;
    div   = a / b;
    resto = a % b;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," A soma  = " + soma);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," A Subtração = " + sub);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," A Multiplicação = "+ mult);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," A divisão = " + div+
                                       "\n O Resto da Divisão = "+resto);  
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Não Pode Dividir!"); 
    } catch (NumberFormatException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Digite números inteiros!");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Fora dos limites permitidos!");
    }    
}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece no seu código é que você primeiro calcula o valor de todas as variáveis e só depois informa o resultado, desta forma assim que o fluxo do algoritmo chega na linha `div = a / b` e caso b seja 0 ele já dispara a `ArithmeticException` e não informa os outros cálculos, para solucionar basta modificar a ordem em que são feitas os cálculos e impressões, você pode por exemplo informar o resultado assim que calcular cada variável, a solução ficaria assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, b, soma, resto, sub, div, mult;
    String entrada;

    try {
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe um número inteiro");
        a = Integer.parseInt(entrada);

        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe outro número inteiro");
        b = Integer.parseInt(entrada);

        soma = a + b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A soma  = " + soma);

        sub = a - b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A Subtração = " + sub);

        mult = a * b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A Multiplicação = " + mult);

        div = a / b;
        resto = a % b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A divisão = " + div +
                "\n O Resto da Divisão = " + resto);
    } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não Pode Dividir!");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite números inteiros!");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fora dos limites permitidos!");
    }
}
```

Nesse caso ele imprime cada calculo assim que for feito e por último tenta fazer a divisão, se `b` for 0 e lançar a `ArithmeticException` apenas o valor da divisão não será informado. Uma outra solução seria tratar a `ArithmeticException` apenas no calculo da divisão já que é apenas este bloco que dispara esse Exception (isto seria o mais recomendado) você poderia fazer assim:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, b, soma, resto, sub, div, mult;
    String entrada;

    try {
        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe um número inteiro");
        a = Integer.parseInt(entrada);

        entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe outro número inteiro");
        b = Integer.parseInt(entrada);

        soma = a + b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A soma  = " + soma);

        sub = a - b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A Subtração = " + sub);

        mult = a * b;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A Multiplicação = " + mult);


        try {
            div = a / b;
            resto = a % b;
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " A divisão = " + div +
                    "\n O Resto da Divisão = " + resto);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Não Pode Dividir!");
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Digite números inteiros!");
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Fora dos limites permitidos!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Era essa  minha duvida, e foi sanada com perfeição! Muito Obrigado.